# how to effect td on fixed table layout

Tags: html, css, fixed

I am trying to animate a table cell without effecting the other cells or the table. I want to change the width and height of a td with a class corresponding on some type of event.I want the td to get bigger and over lap the other cells but without changing their position. How?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="change">
      A
    </td>
    <td class="change">
      B
    </td>
    <td class="change">
     C
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My css would be something like this:

```
table{
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 4em;
 height: 2em;

}

.change{
 width: 1em;
 height: 1em;

}

 .change:hover{
 width: 3em;
 height: 3em;

}
```

So I just want to make the td cell bigger when I hover over it but not effect the other cells position or table at all. How can I do this?

I just want to use CSS but overflow hidden or whitespace none do not work like this and the table moves all over ...

I Added this on an edit.
If I put a div inside each td and scale the div bigger would that work without stretching the table? like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
      A
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="change">
      B
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
     C
      </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you don't want the hover effect to affect other td's, perish the thought of trying to hover. Basically, they will be affected because of the increase in width and height which will gobble up the space allotted to the other td's. As a suggestion, use <div> instead.

Comment: Then What if I made the td position absolute . Would that overlap the other td cells like Im trying to do?

Comment: if you set in absolute position your td , it will get off the flow, you will have 2 cells left to draw your table with one loose tag hover it. have you tried negative margin + padding ? http://fiddle.jshell.net/zK3m3/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**if it is only for visual effect** , you maybe have an option with `transform:scale(3);` to to zoom three times your element. **[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zK3m3/show)**

**To avoid scaling inside content**, do a down scaling , you can set transform-origin. **[other example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zK3m3/1/show)**

**Anyhow**, if you insert more content , `table-layout:fixed;` will still allow *the cell and the whole row to grow vertically.*

Comment: Ahhh cool demo that is awesome and exactly what I want. I could do other effects like rotation and all and it would work too I bet. I will try some. Thanks alot. Plus one!

Comment: Thanks for not telling me to you use divs instead. I am going to make a nice 3d effect with  transform and perspective, it will look cool and I can keep my table the way it is,, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The cells are not separate objects, and are grouped more specifically by their respective columns.  You hover one td, the whole column will expand - pushing all content to the right with it.  Tables are very primitive in their implementation of layouts compared to other methods.  I do not know of a way to interpret table td's as separate objects in which you describe.

I would personally handle this with a div solution instead.